# how to use italic and normal font in a single label-word with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, italic

I want to make a ggplot2 that in the same labels could use italic and normal font, example: wordX and wordY, *word* in italic, and X and Y in normal font: *word*X and *word*Y

I tried something like:

```
data("mtcars")

mtcars$Type <- as.factor(c(rep("wordX", 16), rep("wordY", 16)))

head(mtcars, 3)
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  Type
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 wordX
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 wordX
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 wordX

lbs = brk = levels(mtcars$Type)
lbs[match("wordX", brk)] = expression(italic("word")~X)
lbs[match("wordY", brk)] = expression(italic("word")~Y)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(am), mpg, fill=Type)) +
     geom_col(position="dodge") + 
     theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 18),
           legend.title = element_text(size = 18)) +
     scale_fill_discrete(breaks=brk, labels=lbs)
```

[image]

in the example label *word* X and *word* Y
are separated; how can I plot it together *word*X and *word*Y

How can I make it ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

Use asterisk (`*`) instead of tilde (`~`) in your expressions. The tilde symbol specifies a space, whereas the asterisk will act as a no-space separator.

```r
lbs[match("wordX", brk)] = expression(italic("word")*X)
lbs[match("wordY", brk)] = expression(italic("word")*Y)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(am), mpg, fill=Type)) +
     geom_col(position="dodge") + 
     theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 18),
           legend.title = element_text(size = 18)) +
     scale_fill_discrete(breaks=brk, labels=lbs)
```

[image]